# How can i change Apache's locahost address?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, php, localhost

Sorry for the easy question..
I installed XAMPP.
When i go to localhost in browser, the directory called "c:\xampp\htdocs\"
is opening. I want to change the address of localhost to something like
"d:\works\php\"
Which file/part should i edit?
Thank you

Comment: Find httpd.conf and look for DocumentRoot

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `DocumentRoot setting` in *XAMPP\apache\conf\httpd.conf*:

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\
```

to

```
d:\works\php\
```